# How to check how many numbers in array are under 499?

Tags: java, arrays

I am reading a course in Java and I have solved the essay and everything is working, but one thing. I want to get how many random numbers are in each of the intervals. You can see what I mean by looking at my code below where I have inserted [amount] where I want the number of random numbers. I do not seem to get the right logic. Can anyone help me?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many random numbers from 0 to 999? ");
    int amount = in.nextInt();


    int[] numbers = new int[amount];
    System.out.print("Here is the random numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
    {
        numbers[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");


    System.out.print("These [amount] numbers are from 0 to 499: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
    {
        if (numbers[i] <= 499)
        {
            int[] numbersLow = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length);
            System.out.print(numbersLow[i] + " ");
        }       
    }
    System.out.println("");


    System.out.print("These[amount] numbers are from 500 to 999: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
    {
        if (numbers[i] >= 500)
        {
            int[] numbersHigh = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length);
            System.out.print(numbersHigh[i] + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In your for loop, have a counter variable that goes up every time the if statement is successful, then print it after the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many random numbers from 0 to 999? ");
    int amount = in.nextInt();
    int lowerCounter=0;
    int higherCounter=0;
    List<Integer> lowerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> higherList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int[] numbers = new int[amount];
    System.out.print("Here is the random numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
    {
        numbers[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
        if (numbers[i] <= 499) {
            lowerCounter++;
            lowerList.add(numbers[i]);
        }
        else {
            higherCounter++;
            higherList.add(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");


    System.out.print("These ["+lowerCounter+"] numbers are from 0 to 499: ");
    for (int i:lowerList) 
    {
        System.out.print(i + " ");    
    }
    System.out.println("");


    System.out.print("These ["+higherCounter+"] numbers are from 500 to 999: ");
    for (int i:higherList) 
    {
        System.out.print(i + " ");    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all the System.out part needs to be after the loop, how could you possibly know before? :)

then the   int[] numbersLow does not make any sense to me. If you just want to count the numbers below 500 do it like this:

```
int counterbelow = 0;
System.out.print("These are the numbers between 0 and 499");
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
{
    if (numbers[i] <= 499)
    {
        counterbelow++;
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
    }       
}

System.out.print("These are "+counterbelow+" numbers");
```

Comment: Close, but defining counterbelow in the loop will make it always 0. Define it before the loop. Also, save the list of numbers in a string, and print it after the first println

Comment: `numbersLow[i]` should be `numbers[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Place the ouptut below the loop ;)

```
int amount = 0;
int[] numbersLow = new int[numbers.length];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
{
    if (numbers[i] <= 499)
    {
        numbersLow[amount] = numbers[i];
        amount++;
    }       
}
System.out.println("These " + amount + " numbers are from 0 to 499: ");
for (int n: numbersLow) 
    System.out.print(n + " ")
```